# Is it safe to change NopCommerce layout and components markup ? Will it cause a problem later on updating NopCommerce?

Tags: html, user-interface, themes, upgrade, nopcommerce

Basically I need to change the look and feel of a NopCommerce application, and I have created a separate theme folder and can do my CSS changes there. But there's only so much you can do with CSS. At some point I'll need to update html to make it look like the way I want.

So what I am concerned about is that if I change the layout and individual pages html to make the site look like how I want, what will happen if later I have to upgrade NopCommerce version, will my markup changes break or is it not a problem.

I have seen NopCommerce themes and it looks like they have updated the markup but I am not sure if its right to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already halfway there, it's the same process as for changing the CSS. Simply copy all the *cshtml* files you intend to modify to your theme's folder and change the code however you need to. The modified files should be under *Themes/YourTheme/Views*, as per nopCommerce standard. When you install your theme, it will render the pages from here instead of the default folder. This way, the default views are left untouched, and your changes have no impact on the default theme.

For example, in the default theme of version 4.4, the homepage is rendered from *Themes/DefaultClean/Views/Home/Index.cshtml*. To customize the layout of this page for your theme, copy the *Home* folder to *Themes/YourTheme/Views* and you're good to go.

It's all explained in detail with examples in the official documentation- [Customizing nopCommerce Themes](https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/developer/design/new-theme.html)

Comment: Edited my answer to include the documentation link. I'd suggest going through it for understanding the process better.